# RelativeLayout layout_centerInParent and layout_below issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with laying out a Relative Layout. Here is the test code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/bg_controls"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/controls_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/controls_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result of that is [image]

If I remove android:layout_centerInParent="true" everything works OK. Why does RelativeLayout fails to do that otherwise?

UPD: the intended result is that a second button appears under the LinearLayout.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to make it do?

Comment: the intended result is that a second button appears under the LinearLayout. I thought that was obvious...

Comment: by under the linearlayout, do you mean below the linearLayout?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific regarding the image itself instead of the layouts?

Comment: RelativeLayout is behaving correctly in this case and you need to add layout_below parameter to get the intended result for button 2

Comment: what about the image? There is a background with placeholders cut out for some controls. Those controls are in the linearLayout which has layout_centerInParent="true". Other buttons should be below this layout but for some reason they are not.

Comment: Try to define the `android:layout_gravity="center"` in your button and remove the `layout_centerInParent="true"` and then check.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue, where I had a centered `View` that was designated `layout_centerInParent`, and all my other Views were relative to that, but some of the `View`s were not rendering properly in the editor or on the device.

I found that my centered `View` itself, designated `layout_centerInParent`, still had to be relative to something else (as unintuitive as that sounds).  So I made it `layout_below` something that was on top of it, even though that `View` on top of it was not aligned to anything except being `layout_top` of the same thing below.  But once I did this, the whole UI snapped into place :)

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the relative layout is having height wrap_content. If you can give fixed height to the relative layout, the layout_below the centerInParent item works fine. Otherwise the relative layout assumes the position of the first item (here the controls_layout) in the usual position (that is, without centerInparent) and aligns the second item below it.

---

solutions:

1. Give fixed height to relative layout instead of wrap_content
   or
2. keep the two buttons in a linear layout with orientation vertical, and give centerInParent to the linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Are you using API level 3 (1.5)?  RelativeLayouts are very quirky for 1.5.  Giving your buttons an id is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this on an actual device? I got this problem when previewing the layout in eclipse, but when I ran it on a device, it worked as intended